# Matching balancing records by pulling record type code

Tags: sql-server

I have a view that contains transaction records such as the following 
example.

[image]

I need to find a way to relate records 1 & 2, 3 & 4 and 5, 6 & 7 so I can then copy the code from the last column over to the balancing record's row.

Sometimes the records have matching values but in other cases there are 2 or more records that add up to the balancing record (rows 5, 6, and 7).

I need to maybe be able to add a column that would number them based on grouping, so rows 1 & 2 would be number 1, rows 3 & 4 number 2, rows 5, 6 & 7 number 3 etc.

Or just another way to ensure I can pass the A from row 1 over to 2, the B from row 3 over to 4, and the A from row 6 over to 5 and 7.

I guess my question is, is there a way to have the view match up the records that balance each other in this way?

Comment: For an incredibly simplistic example like yours, you could probably do that, but looking at those columns, I cannot see anything unique about the rows that would allow you to identify what belongs to what in the case of conflicts. For example, let's say you have 6 debit entries (20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 50) and 3 credit entries (20, 60, 70), all with the same ID, how would you go about matching them? Or can you just match them in any way so long as they're under the same ID?

Comment: How do you know record 4 must be grouped with record 3 and not record 1? All records have the same ID. It´s just by the order of rows? Rows in a database are not sorted. Selecting rows without the order clause can return rows in any order. And if you use sort by id, these 4 rows can be returned in any order.

Comment: How do 1 and 2 balance if they are on different accounts?  I am with @ZLK you seem to need another column that relates associated debits and credits to a unique entity.  Also, I would say you're going to want more meaningful column names.  Is ID the user Id that posted the transaction, a transaction id (that should prob be unique)?  If the 2 transactions are related shouldn't they be on the same account?  What does "Account" mean in your context? etc etc

Comment: The ID is a Journal ID, meaning someone manually input the records. I agree that this should be unique to matching records but the way my company has been inputting information is that they can put multiple pairs of matching records in at once and they fall under the same ID. As far as differing accounts, certain accounts numbers belong just to "Account Receivables" or "Account Payables", they are used to balance the transactions to the other accounts, so they go together. As long as the values match (even w/ a sum in the 2:1 scenario) and under same ID, then I need to give them the same code

Comment: As far as your example @ZLK, the numbers in the 'Value' column as generally so specific that the changes of having more than 2 records that balance each other, or even multiple credit/debit records under the same ID that when summed will be equal is almost non-existent. I know this isn't an ideal scenario as I would love for there to be another column that is unique to matching records but no such luck and I am still expected to figure this out. At this point I just need to match them in any way so long as they are under the same ID and debit/credit values balance each other out